# Fixing The jQuery Slideshow Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, slideshow

Hi I am new to jQuery and I have created a simple slideshow plugin called IPage Slides. Problem is when I click the start button multiple times slide loading times gets faster and sometimes browser get stuck.

http://www.innovativephp.com/ipage-slides

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code innovative-pslides-switch.js everytime startSlide is invoked you dont clear the previous timer and the startSlide is called with another timer, this is causing it to be updated multiple times.

The correct approach should be stop the previous slide and then create a new slide, after all user just needs the slide and there should be only one timer doing the slide.